ConnectionError in SQL Server
I'm connecting NodeJs with SQL Server and get this error:

ConnectionError: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
at PrivateConnection.callback2 (D:\test\node_modules\mssql\lib\msnodesqlv8\connection-pool.js:46:1

This my Index.js file:
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const path = require('path');
const { engine } = require('express-handlebars');
const {conn, sql} = require('./connect')

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// http logger
app.use(morgan('combined'));

// template engine
app.engine('hbs', engine({
  extname: '.hbs'
}));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'resoures/views'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('home');
});

app.get('/tin-tuc', (req, res) => {
 
  res.render('tin');
});

app.get('/search', (req, res) => {
  res.render('search');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`);
});

And this my connect.js file:
const sql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8');

const config = {
    server: "DESKTOP-0BKJQ7L\MAY1",
    database: "testnodejs",
    driver: "msnodesqlv8",
    options: {
        trustedConnection: true // Dùng cho Windows Authentication
    }
};

const conn = new sql.ConnectionPool(config).connect().then(pool => {
    console.log('Connected to SQL Server');
    return pool;
}).catch(err => {
    console.error('Database Connection Failed!', err);
    return Promise.reject(err);
});

module.exports = {
    conn: conn,
    sql: sql,
};


I want to connect NodeJs with my SQL Server database.

From the documentation, it seems you should be using the connectionString configuration option
